# Foreach loop not working for sqllite in php

Tags: php, database, sqlite, foreach, while-loop

I want to use foreach for looping instead of while loop in the below code. But for some reason the foreach loop is not working as I expected. Can please help me with this.

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
 {
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('test.db');
  }
  }
  $db = new MyDB();
  if(!$db){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
  } else {
  echo "Opened database successfully\n";
  }

  $sql =<<<EOF
  SELECT * from COMPANY;
  EOF;
  $ret = $db->query($sql);
  $newArray = array_chunk($links['data'], 12, false);
  while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
  echo "ID = ". $row['ID'] . "\n";
  echo "NAME = ". $row['NAME'] ."\n";
  echo "ADDRESS = ". $row['ADDRESS'] ."\n";
  echo "SALARY =  ".$row['SALARY'] ."\n\n";
  }
  echo "Operation done successfully\n";
  $db->close();
```

THis is the code I Used.

```
$ret = $db->query($sql);
$value = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
foreach($value as $row){
  echo "ID = ". $row['ID'] . "\n";
  echo "NAME = ". $row['NAME'] ."\n";
  echo "ADDRESS = ". $row['ADDRESS'] ."\n";
  echo "SALARY =  ".$row['SALARY'] ."\n\n";
}
echo "Operation done successfully\n";
$db->close();
```

Comment: Could you post your code for the foreach loop (what you tried & didn't work)?

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen with the foreach loop and what happens when you run it.

Comment: @ShaneSmith Updated the question with the code I used.

Comment: @Jite It throws "Illegal string offset" error for all the values fetched from the DB

Comment: You can't replace while with foreach in this case. Is there any specific reason to use foreach ?

Comment: It looks like `$value = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);` is only getting the first row, and storing it in `$value`. You want to store **all** rows in `$value`.

Try `foreach ($ret as $row)` instead? I haven't used SQLite with PHP, so I'm unsure if that will work.

Comment: @Rikesh I want to split the data into array chunks. I already written the code for it with Foreach. So i want to make it adapt to it

Comment: Than you can have workaround by fetching all values first using while loop than use that values in foreach loop.

Comment: @ShaneSmith nope it didn't work

Comment: @winnyboy5 Okay, try Rikesh's suggestion regarding using the while loop first to store it how you want it, then loop over the new variable with foreach.

Comment: @Rikesh Guess that will work. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @Rikesh That work around worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code worked for me.

```
  $sql =<<<EOF
  SELECT * from COMPANY;
  EOF;
  $ret = $db->query($sql);
  while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
  $data[]=array('id'=>$row['ID'],'name'=>$row['NAME'],'address'=>$row['ADDRESS'],'salary'=>$row['SALARY']);
  }
  echo "Operation done successfully\n";
  $db->close();
  foreach($data as $val){
 echo $val['id'].'<br>'.$val['address'].'<br>'.$val['salary'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe im late for this but anyway

foreach sample

```
    foreach ($ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) as $row) {
      echo "<pre>";
      $array[] = $row;
    }

    echo $array[0] ."\n";
    echo $array[1] ."\n";
    echo $array[2] ."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not works with SQlite3 class, but using PDO...

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:(your path)test.db');
$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT * from COMPANY;
EOF;

$ret = $db->query($sql);

foreach($ret as $row){
  echo "ID = ". $row['ID'] . "\n";
  echo "NAME = ". $row['NAME'] ."\n";
  echo "ADDRESS = ". $row['ADDRESS'] ."\n";
  echo "SALARY =  ".$row['SALARY'] ."\n\n";
}
```

SQlite3 class not works in Laravel too. PDO works. I'm using PHP 8 and Laravel 8.

Where i found it: https://www.a2hosting.com.br/kb/developer-corner/sqlite/connect-to-sqlite-using-php